# ADPCMデコード時のアイデアについて

Tags: c

以下の様な無線デバイスの開発を行っています。

1. 親機と子機となるデバイスがあり、デジタル無線で通信を行っている。
2. 子機は環境音の収集を行い10kHz/16bitサンプルデータをADPCM(4bit)に圧縮して、1パケット(約)160バイトずつ親機へ送信する。
3. 親機は子機から受信したデータを伸張して再生する。
4. 親機は子機からのデータを取りこぼした場合、受信する予定だったデータを0x00(1パケット取りこぼしたら0x00*160バイトの)として補完する。

※子機は片方向で音声データを送信しており、親機はそれに対するACKの様なものは応答しない。

ADPCMは過去のサンプルデータと現在のサンプルデータの差分を利用したアルゴリズムである為、上記4の処理を行ってしまうと、そのタイミングで再生音が意図しない音になってしまいます。
具体的には著しく、音量が低下します（このメカニズムもなぜかはわかっていません...）。

電話などの開発を行ったことがある方で、音声が途切れる時のデコード処理などの工夫をしたことがある方など、ノウハウをご教示頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データエラーをある程度許容するマルチメディア通信（音声通信・映像通信）を仮定した一般論をいくつか提示します。

- [A] データ中に「同期ポイント」を定期送信する。例: 映像コーデックの"キーフレーム"。
- [B] データとともにエラー訂正符号を同時送信する。例: FEC(Forward Error Correction)。
- [C] 受信側でデータ異常を検知した場合は再送要求を行う。例: RTP/RTCP通信によるパケット再送要求。
- [D] 通信トランスポート層に高信頼プロトコルを用いる。例: TCP上で行われるHLS(HTTP Live Streaming)。SCTP(Stream Control Transmission Protocol)。

今回利用されるADPCM符号化では、データ破損点に続くデータを正しくデコードすることが**原理的に**出来ません。少なくとも[A]（または[D]）対応が必須になります。つまりデータ破損点から次の同期ポイントまでのデータは諦め、同期ポイントから改めてデコードを再開することになります。

---

> ADPCMは過去のサンプルデータと現在のサンプルデータの差分を利用したアルゴリズムである為、上記4の処理を行ってしまうと、そのタイミングで再生音が意図しない音になってしまいます。
>   具体的には著しく、音量が低下します。

既に言及されている通り、過去サンプルデータを強制的に0x00としているため、デコーダ側では値0からの差分値（つまり非常に小さな値）として復号しています。言い換えると、データ破損点を境にPCMデータの絶対値が失われています。

Comment: 大変、有益な情報です。ありがとうございます。「同期ポイント」を設けるというアドバイスで光が見えてきました。具体的な方法はイメージがあるので、現実的に対応できそうです。